# What's wrong with this (mm-dd-yyyy) regular expression?

Tags: regex, date

I'm trying to validate mm-dd-(2012~2099) date format.

I have the following regular expression.

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[10-31])-(20[12-99])$
```

when I run the following code, I get false. What's wrong with this regular expression?

```
var reg = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[10-31])-(20[12-99])$")
reg.test("05-33-2012")**
```

When I take out the year part, and then test "05-33", it works.

Comment: `[12-99]` does not do what you think (neither does `[10-31]` for that matter).  (Unless there's an extension I'm unaware of...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth // Got it. Totally misunderstood numbers in regular expression. http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: To avoid any doubt: there are *no numbers* in regular expressions: they're just sequences of characters like any other text.

Comment: Do you really have to do this in a single regex? Would be easier to validate format and extract the three fields, and then validate as a date (not such ranges) eg. `02-29-2012` is valid but `02-29-2013` is not.

Comment: @Richard // Well..I could go that way, but I'm using a validator that my co-worker created. Basically it take a string and regexp. I like to keep using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Oli said, [12-99] does not do what you think it does.

Specifically, the `-` refers to a range of *characters*, not numbers. So `[12-99]` matches...

```
1
2-9
9
```

The expression `20(1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9])` would work for dates 2012-2099